# Android - Break line between text views

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, textview

I've created a ListView which display 2 textviews per each entry.
The info in them is present without any issues. I've to rearrange both TextViews, but I cannot get them to appear one below the other.

The goal is:
Desc: XXXXXXXXXXX
Assigned To: XXXXXXXXXXX

Thank you in advance.

**Here is the layoutXML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/TskRowlinearLayout1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tskdesc_label"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Desc:"/>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/taskDesc"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/TskRowlinearLayout2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emp_name_label"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Assigned To:"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/employee_name"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout >
```

**Screenshot**
[image: The row appear, Desc is correct, but the goal is to place "assigned to" below it, not next to it.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do a printf, to format the size of your string
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html

I think the expand you will get a problem, because in some devices, the string will be  bigger to the screen.
With format you can solve like this
 System.out.format("Desc: %s Assigned To: %s", desc, assigned);

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.
What about placing them one below the other? same issue?

Comment: To do it one below to other, create an Adapter to listView
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#androidlists_adapterintro

Comment: I tried doing this in my existing Adapter but I was unsuccessful, can you view my Adapter code perhaps?

Comment: Look here in http://guides.codepath.com/android#adapterviews
there are one example 
http://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView